# Sails/Waterline: How can I stub an instance function of a model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, sails.js, waterline

We've got some instance functions on our models, and we can test those just fine. But when trying to test a different function that loads a waterline instance and then calls the instance function, we'd like to stub that call to the instance function.

For example, the function we're trying to unit test might look like this:

```
testFunction: function (id, cb) {
  Model.findOne(id, function (err, model) {
    model.instanceFunction();
    cb(null, model);
  });
}
```

I want to stub `model.instanceFunction`, but can't figure out how to do it. `Model.prototype` doesn't seem to exist at all. I can stub `Model._instanceMethods`, but the instance function isn't actually the function on the instance of the model, so that doesn't work.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: please use test-double tools as sinon.js. You only have to code like this, sinon.stub(Model, 'instanceFunction', function(){// do as  you like })

Comment: We are using sinon.js, but what you've described is the process for stubbing a class function, not an instance function. We need to stub the instance functions that are members of the waterline object returned from a `find` or something similar.

Comment: Very sorry, I misunderstood, and understood the difficulty you have, by reading, /waterline/lib/waterline/core/index.js

Comment: No problem. You pointed me in the right direction with that last comment. Will have to dig into it but hoping there's something in there that makes it possible. https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/lib/waterline/core/index.js

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Never found a great solution. We simply started stubbing the waterline function that was returning the instance. So, in the example above, we stubbed `Model.findOne` to return an object that we already stubbed. Not necessarily ideal, but gets the job done